# Does Mac's PHP interfere with XAMPP/MAMP's PHP?

Tags: php, macos, xdebug

This is a follow-up question of this [post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/230017/need-some-basic-enlightenment-about-using-php).

I was trying to install xDebug following this [instruction](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/xdebug-professional-php-debugging--net-34396). In its "Install Xdebug" section, after doing "brew install php54-xdebug", it starts operating under MAMP'safolder. Here is what I got confused:

I never used MAMP before but I think it is about the same thing with XAMPP. To my understanding, XAMPP comes with its own PHP copy, independent from the one already installed on(or come with) Mac OS. When I did "brew install php54-xdebug", I think I install xdebug to OSX's PHP, does this also affect MAMP's PHP? If yes, MAMP's PHP is somewhat interfering with OSX's PHP?

Or, when I copy the "xdebug.so" file, I am actually copying the xdebug extension from one PHP copy to another? And after doing this, I am actually having two xdebug extensions on my Mac? If so, why can't directly install xdebug to the MAMP's PHP?

Many questions because some key concepts need to be clarified for me.

Comment: I am trying to understand some basic concepts, so that I get answers for other questions by myself. In this question I am not seeking to solve actual problem, I just don't understand a part of the instruction. So I didn't include my software, which is XAMPP by the way.

Comment: I think there are some key basic concepts about how PHP works unclear to me, which PHP developers and technical article authors neglects to mention, that is why I have so much trouble understanding some certain things.

Comment: Maybe it's my English, but I think I have done my best to ask my question: Is there any relationship between the php of OSX and the php of MAMP?

Comment: I thought the answer was no before I read the linked instruction. The instruction lets me install xdebug to PHP of OSX and then operates on MAMP, which makes me conclude that there is some relationship between them. If yes, what is it?